# Is it possible to implement a `Wingpanel.Indicator` instance in Python?

Tags: wingpanel, python

I'm looking to write a quick indicator applet for international timezones, since Elementary doesn't have any kind of world clock functionality. Being familiar with Python, I'd rather do it in that, but I'm only seeing the old `gi.repository` -> `AppIndicator3` API, which doesn't support very rich widgets.

Any recommendations? I'm not particularly interested in learning Vala.

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved, as I'm also looking for a timezone applet?

Comment: What I found is that the Python tools immediately available really only support the old school d-bus menu system, which made for a pretty lousy UX. I did experiment with a timezone applet, but with it just showing menu items, I moved on. I can send you the github snippet if I still have it, but it isn't very pretty.

Comment: I may just learn Vala to get this implemented.

Comment: Also interested in tinkering with this API via Python. What are some examples of things that use the "old school d-bus menu system"? What does that look like, and how does it limit you?